# How to make customer can not order product price '0'

Tags: orders, price

How to make customer can not order product price '0'?

(I setup the stock number first and then setup price days later due to some reason.

Before I setup the price, customer order products with price '0' and I have to contact the

customer about the issue :(

Comment: @Marius I tried that but I found sometime I forgot to enable and that also make problem while 'disable to enable' Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make them disabled until you add a price. Or set it out of stock. Leave the stock qty as it is, but set the flag "Stock status" to out of stock. Then set it back in stock when you add the price.

Comment: Make Out of Stock is kind of solution Thank you!